# Counting number of occurrences of word in java

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I want to count the number of occurrences of particular word in a source string.
Let's say src="thisisamangoterrthisismangorightthis?"
     word="this"
So what I am doing is, first search for index of word in src. It's at index 0. Now I am extracting the part from this index location to end of src.
i.e., now src="isamangoterrthisismangorightthis?" and search for word again.
But I am getting array out of bound exception.

```
public static int countOccur(String s1, String s2)
{
    int ans=0;
    int len1=s1.length();
    int len2=s2.length();
    System.out.println("Lengths:"+len1+" " +len2);

    while(s1.contains(s2))
    {
        ans++;
        int tmpInd=s1.indexOf(s2);
        System.out.println("Now Index is:"+tmpInd);
        if((tmpInd+len2)<len1){
            s1=s1.substring(tmpInd+len2, len1);
            System.out.println("Now s1 is:"+s1);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return ans;

}
```

Comment: You never recalculate len1, so it keeps the length of the first string, even though s1 get smaller, which explains your exception. Just use substring(int) which cuts from the given index till the end f the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to count the word in a string,

```
private static int countingWord(String value, String findWord)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (value.contains(findWord))
        {
            int index = value.indexOf(findWord);
            value = value.substring(index + findWord.length(), value.length());
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a method that throws [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), it's always a good idea to check the bounds. See [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

> **IndexOutOfBoundsException** - if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex`
>   is larger than the length of this String object, or `beginIndex` is
>   larger than `endIndex`.

---

You should cover all cases:

```
if(tmpInd + len2 >= s1.length() || len1 >= s1.length() || ... ) {
    //Not good
}
```

Or, better, you should consider your logic to avoid this situation in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use `indexOf()`, it will take care of bounds etc for you:

```
public static int countOccurrences(final String haystack, final String needle)
{
    int index = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    while (true) {
        index = haystack.indexOf(needle, index);
        if (index == -1)
            return ret;
        ret++;
    }

    // Not reached
    throw new IllegalStateException("How on earth did I get there??");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a `substring` on your String use this method

```
public int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)
```

then just check if the result is `-1`

Answer (score 0):

Your might use replace to solve the problem

```
String s = "thisisamangoterrthisismangorightthis?";
String newS = s.replaceAll("this","");
int count = (s.length() - newS.length()) / 4;
```

Comment: I like this way XD but put a variable for `"this"` and use it in count compute ;)

Comment: Use `.replace()` instead of `.replaceAll()` since you replace a literal text here. Unlike what its name implies, `.replace()` _does_ replace all occurrences. But to start with, why do that when solutions which don't require new string creation exist? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordCount
{
public static class Word implements Comparable<Word>
{
    String word;
    int count;

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return word.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return word.equals(((Word)obj).word);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word b)
    {
        return b.count - count;
    }
}


    public  static void findWordcounts(File input)throws Exception
    {
       long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Map<String, Word> countMap = new HashMap<String, Word>();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new    FileInputStream(input)));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = line.split("[^A-ZÃ…Ã„Ã–a-zÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶]+");
        for (String word : words) {
            if ("".equals(word)) {
                continue;
            }

            Word wordObj = countMap.get(word);
            if (wordObj == null) {
                wordObj = new Word();
                wordObj.word = word;
                wordObj.count = 0;
                countMap.put(word, wordObj);
            }

            wordObj.count++;
        }
    }

    reader.close();

    SortedSet<Word> sortedWords = new TreeSet<Word>(countMap.values());
    int i = 0;
    for (Word word : sortedWords) {
        if (i > 10) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Word \t "+ word.word+"\t Count \t"+word.count);

        i++;
    }

    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

    System.out.println("Completed in " + time + " ms"); 
    }


public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
   findWordcounts(new File("./don.txt"));               
}
}
```