# Java searching for string keyword in each line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a program that is searching for keyword "word" by scanner in each line of java file.

The body of function I've done:

```
Scanner scaner = new Scanner(file);
int count = 0;
String search  = "word";
while (scaner.hasNext()) {
    Scanner scaner2 = new Scanner(scaner.nextLine());
    while (scaner2.hasNext()) {
        String s = scaner.next();
        System.out.println(s);
        if ( s.indexOf(search) != -1 ) count++; 
    }
}
```

I need to count the "word" even if it looks like "//subword" or "wordwordword"

Anyone may help me?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm

You'll want to check not only that it equals word but also check to see if it contains word.

Comment: You may want to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755915/counting-number-of-occurrences-of-word-in-java

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet should do what you're trying to achieve:

```
String str = "wordwordwordwordword";
String search = "word";
int occurrence = str.split(search, -1).length - 1;
System.out.println(occurrence); // Occurrence = 5
```

The split() method will split the "str" based on "search" string for as many times as possible, and we can get the occurrence by deducting the length of the array by 1. You may refer to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) for more information on the method.

Hope this helps!